# RPM + SPEC file - header source

Tags: linux, rpm

I have the following spec file (below), I want to add to the Source - `/root/calculate.sh`

How do I add second source ?

For example

`Source: /root/test.sh /root/calculate.sh` ( is illegal)

The SPEC file

```
 Summary: An example tool. To show a simple rpm build of the tool.
 Name: test.sh
 Version: 6.2
 Release: 2
 Source: /root/test.sh 
 URL: http://www.gnomovision.com/cdplayer/cdplayer.html
 Group: Development/Debuggers
 BuildRoot:/tmp/MY_RPM_TESTS
 License: OtherLicense
 %description

 %install
 rm -rf %{buildroot}

 mkdir -p %{buildroot}/home
 mkdir -p %{buildroot}/home/home1

cp %SOURCE0 %{buildroot}/home
cp %SOURCE0 %{buildroot}/home/home1

%pre -p /bin/ksh
uname -a

%files
/home/test.sh
/home/home1/test.sh


%post -p /bin/ksh

/home/home1/test.sh

uname -a
print "Now we wait for sleep" ; sleep  1
NUM=100
print $NUM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this information on TLDP's [RPM-HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/RPM-HOWTO/build.html)

Quote:

> You can also specify more than one source file using lines like:

```
Source0: blah-0.tar.gz
Source1: blah-1.tar.gz
Source2: fooblah.tar.gz
```